# Master key implementation for AWS Cognito authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Here are the steps for a user to be authenticated using Cognito:

1. Browser asks to access a restricted page.
2. The JavaScript on the loaded page looks for `id_token` on the URL page. If it is not found, the browser is redirected to the Cognito's sign in page where the user needs to enter username and password.
3. Once the user is authenticated, the browser is redirected back to the original restricted page with an `id_token` in the URL.
4. The JavaScript on the restricted page uses this `id_token` to call API Gateway.

Now, I have a different scenario in mind. Assume there's a safe connection and whoever uses that connection to access the restricted page does not need to be authenticated. In other words, their identity is assumed and they will not be asked to authenticate themselves. Instead, they will be taken to the restricted pages as one particular user (each secure connection will represent one fixed particular user). For simplicity, you can assume that secured connections are identified by IP. In this scenario, the above steps will change to:

1. Browser asks to access a restricted page.
2. The JavaScript on the loaded page looks for `id_token` on the URL page. If it is not found, some API on the server is called.
3. Using the IP address of the incoming request, the API called will recognize the user and return the `id_token` for them without asking for any password.
4. The JavaScript on the restricted page uses this `id_token` to call API Gateway.

The key requirement here is that I'm looking for a way to implement these two in parallel. What I mean is that each user should be able to access the restricted page from a secured connection without a password and from a non-secured connection using a password. In other words, the API called on the second scenario should be able to return the `id_token` for a user without knowing their password. Or maybe using a master-key password.

**So here's my question. Is there any way I can return some user's `id_token` without knowing their password?**

P.S. I know IPs are not secure enough for this implementation. It was just a mean to simplify the question. Please don't worry about the feasibility of providing an actual secure mean to verify the authenticity of the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer myself. It's called `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow. There are multiple steps you need to take to implement this:

First, go to Cognito console and then, click on your user pool. Go to `triggers` page and introduce a lambda function for `Define Auth Challenge`. The simplest code for this lambda function looks like this:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    event.response.challengeName = "";
    event.response.issueTokens = true;
    event.response.failAuthentication = false;
    callback(null, event);
};
```

Second and last, create your lambda function to authenticate your users:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
    var params = {
      AuthFlow: 'CUSTOM_AUTH',
      ClientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX', /* required */
      UserPoolId: 'XXXXXXXXXX', /* required */
      AuthParameters: {
        'USERNAME': 'XXXXXXXXXX', //Username / Email
      },
    };
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminInitiateAuth(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            callback(null, err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);           // successful response
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

As you can see the code does not need the password and it returns all the tokens that you need (id_token, access_token, and refresh_token etc.).